# How to delete a row in TableLayout dynamically

Tags: android

I am having a TableLayout for which I added rows dynamically.In each of the row there are 2 elements of which one is TextView other is Button.When I click the button that is present in a row,that row should be deleted.How can this be done in Android ? How to find rowid and how to delete a row dynamically.
can anyone help me in sorting out this issue.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: can anyone help me in sorting out this issue?

Comment: Refer the following [Deleting the dynamically added rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796075/how-to-horizontally-align-some-programmatically-added-views) which is working well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this kind of approach:

```
    TableRow tableRow;
    TextView tv;
    Button button;
    //...
    tableRow.addView(tv)
    tableRow.addView(button);


    //somewhere where you want to delete
    ViewGroup parent=button.getParent();
    if(parent instanceof TableRow)
        //do deleting task
```

Comment: Currrently my design is changed I am dynamically adding Textview and checkbox as a row to table. Outside table I have a button. When I click the button and if check box is selected in any row, then that particular row should be deleted.How to know which checkbox is checked ?As I need to know whether it is ViewParent or ViewGroup

Comment: You need to know TableLayout handle and using it's handle you can enumerate all available child views, so you'd know checkboxes. As you'd know checkbox you can have it's TableRow

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      TableRow t = (TableRow) v.getParent();
      TextView firstTextView = (TextView) t.getChildAt(0);
      code = firstTextView.getText().toString();

      System.out.println("code>>>>>>" + code);

      View row = (View) v.getParent();
      // container contains all the rows, you could keep a
      // variable somewhere else to the container which you
      // can refer to here
      ViewGroup container = ((ViewGroup) row.getParent());
      // delete the row and invalidate your view so it gets
      // redrawn
      container.removeView(row);
      container.invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign tags or id's when you adding a row. Then just use that tag/id to delete that row.

```
TableLayout table;  // global access, probably initialized in onCreate()

// initialization, etc.
```

Create element that will be added to the TableLayout, a TableRow with the TextView and the Button then call `addDeleteClick(yourButton, uniqueTag)` before adding it to the TableLayout.

```
// example of adding a text view and a button the the TableLayout
void addToTableLayout(String text, String uniqueTag) {
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(yourActivity);
    // set the unique tag that will be used when deleting this row
    tr.setTag(uniqueTag);
    // do what you need with the button and textview
    TextView tv = new TextView(yourActivity);
    tv.setText(text);
    Button bt = new Button(yourActivity);
    // add delete click capability to the button
    addDeleteClick(bt, uniqueTag);
    table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}

// Adds the delete on click capability to a button 
// to delete a row from TableLayout based on its tag
void addDeleteClick(Button bt, final String tag) {
    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Log.d("TableLayout", " deleting row with tag " + tag);
            deleteRow(tag);
        }

    });
}

// delete a row from TableLayout based on its tag
void deleteRow(String tag) {
    View removedRow = table.findViewWithTag(tag);
    table.removeView(removedRow);
    table.invalidate();
}
```