# How to horizontally  align some programmatically added views?

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment

I have designed a layout as in the image below:

[image]

After entering text in the `EditText`, when I press the *Add+* `Button` the `TextView` and `Button` will be added as shown in the image below:

[image]

I want to show the `Button` on the right side of  the `TextView`. How should I do this?
Another question, how should I remove corresponding `View` when user clicks a button? The code:

```
 public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
    private LinearLayout mLayout;
    private EditText mEditText;
    private Button mButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mLayout.addView(createNewTextView(mEditText.getText()
                        .toString()));
                mLayout.addView(createNewButton());
            }
        });

    }

    private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
        final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        textView.setText("New text: " + text);
        return textView;
    }

    private Button createNewButton() {
        final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        button.setText(" - ");
        return button;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextViews` and `Buttons` are stacked because you probably use a `LinearLayout` with the orientation `vertical`. You could wrap your `TextView` + `Button` into a `LinearLayout` and then add this `LinearLayout` to your own layout or you could use a `TableLayout` like below(I've added some ids so you can delete the rows you want):

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText mInput;
        private TableLayout mTable;
        private static int sCount = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
            mInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            mTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table1);
            addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mTable.addView(addRow(mInput.getText().toString()));
                }
            });
        }

        private TableRow addRow(String s) {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setId(1000 + sCount);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            TableRow.LayoutParams tlparams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setLayoutParams(tlparams);
            textView.setText("New text: " + s);
            tr.addView(textView);
            TableRow.LayoutParams blparams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            final Button button = new Button(this);
            button.setLayoutParams(blparams);
            button.setText(" - ");
            button.setId(2000 + sCount);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {               
                    mTable.removeView(findViewById(v.getId() - 1000));
                }           
            });
            tr.addView(button);
            sCount++;
            return tr;
    }

}
```

where the `main` layout file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

If for some reason, you don't like the `TableLayout` use a `LinearLayout` to wrap you `TextView` and `Button` with the layout file above(and of course remove the `TableLayout`):

```
//...
ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //where ll is the LinearLayout with the id parent
                ll.addView(addRow(mInput.getText().toString()));
            }
        });
    }

    private LinearLayout addRow(String s) {
        LinearLayout tr = new LinearLayout(this);
        tr.setId(1000 + sCount);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams tlparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(tlparams);
        textView.setText("New text: " + s);
        tr.addView(textView);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams blparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setLayoutParams(blparams);
        button.setText(" - ");
        button.setId(2000 + sCount);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                ll.removeView(findViewById(v.getId() - 1000));
            }           
        });
        tr.addView(button);
        sCount++;
        return tr;
    }
```

Comment: button.setId(2000 + sCount); Can you please just tell me what is the use of this?

Comment: @user1398150 In order to delete the `Views` from the layout you need a reference to them. That reference is the `id` that I set. When ever you add a new row in your layout(`TextView` and `Button`) I set an `int` value as the id(1000 + sCount, where sCount is incremented each time so the rows have ids like 1000, 1001, 1002 etc). I also set an `id` of `2000 + sCount`(2000, 2001, 2002 etc) for the `Button` to know which `Button` from which row was clicked.

Comment: I understood it but i thought that for button it's not necessary.so that's why asked you.Ok Anyway thanks.

Comment: @user1398150 Actually setting that `id` for the `Button` is very important if you want to delete rows. As you see, in the `onClick` method I get the `id` from `v`(which represents the `Button` that was clicked). Because I know that the `id` of the `Button` is the `id` of the enclosing `TableRow`/`LinearLayout` + 1000 , it's easy to find the `View` to delete.

Comment: Yup.thank you once again Luksprog for the explanation.Now I got the clear picture.

Comment: I replaced textview with spinner it's getting correct adding for table view. I have couple of items in the spinner.according to needs user'll select the item from the spinner.Now i need to access that data.when i'm calling tableview i'm getting the childcount of the view,but i need to access that data but as it is a view i'm getting "android.widget.TableRow@4103c468" of code.so how can i access the code help me pls.

Comment: @user1398150 Please post a new question and better explain there what you're trying to do and what is actually happening.

Comment: @Lusksprog posted Q at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928288/getting-data-from-table-view

Comment: @LuksprogHave u deleted to post in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928288/getting-data-from-tablelayout

Answer (score 1):

LinearLayout having the property Orientation to align control either Vertically/Horizontally 
so just set Orientation of the same

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

```
 mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
 mLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

Updated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout   
        xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";   
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" > 

<LinearLayout   
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

<EditText   
        android:id="@+id/editText" 
        android:layout_width="293dp"   
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" > 
        <requestFocus /> </EditText> 

 <Button android:id="@+id/button" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Add+" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the first view is changing to horizontal and when i'm adding the text it is not showing any thing

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="293dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add+" />

</LinearLayout>

Comment: when i'm adding more then one it needs to show one after the other but it is showing all at the right side of the view.