# How to create view like Addcontacts view in android?

Tags: android, layout, view

As per my requirement i need to create a view like following view

[image]

but my problem is, i'm able to add a new view to the existing view but
as i mentioned [in this i'm unable to move forward from this flaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796075/how-to-align-views-in-horizontally-through-programmatic-in-android)  ,can anybody 
help me  in solving this. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to fully replicate the screen above or simply create the screen from your other question?

Comment: i want to create the screen from the other question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Got Answer in the following link.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796075/how-to-horizontally-align-some-programmatically-added-views/10811884#10811884)