# how to build Below kind of JSON Format to post it as a request in android?

Tags: android, json, post

Ineed to post data in JSON format as shown below And the **size** of the array is not 
**constant.** it depends on the user.

```
  {
  "info": [
    {
      "Name": "foo1",
      "Number": 123
    },
    {
      "Name": "foo2",
      "Number": 124
    },
    {
      "Name": "foo2",
      "Number": 125
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to create in the following way

```
JSONObject parent = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject childObj = new JSONObject();


childObj.put("Name", etName.getText()).toString();
childObj.put("Number", etNumber.getText()).toString();

jArray.put(childObj);

parent.put("info",jArray);
```

but i'm unable to get it and I also tried in this way like [example 6.1](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples) but there is no method like add for JSONArray. So how can post my data. Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what your question is but I'd typically do something like this to create the JSON string that you are looking for (the example below is using the org.json reference implementation from http://www.json.org/java/index.html):

```
JSONObject parent = new JSONObject();
JSONArray infoArray = new JSONArray();


for(int i = 0; i < SOMEARRAY.length; i++)
{
    JSONObject childObj = new JSONObject();
    childObj.put("Name", etName.getText());
    childObj.put("Number", etNumber.getText());
    infoArray.put(childObj);
}

parent.put("info", infoArray);

String encodedJsonString = parent.toString();
```

Comment: Whats not working? You gotta give a bit more detail than that. Are you using the reference implementation? Did you change the for loop to suit your needs (or remove the for loop entirely). Its hard to know what you are trying to do just by looking at your question. What is it in my code that is not working?

Comment: the childObj is not getting added to Array.

Comment: It should work, are you sure that your code is correct? Try updating your post with the current state of your code. What happen if you change `etName.getText()` to a hard coded string? Are you getting any exceptions? Have you modified so that the for-loop that I added is working for your cause?

Comment: yes but as in my earlier post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809975/how-to-create-view-like-addcontacts-view-in-android i need to add some fields and then i need to get it from there in that place it is missing to add it to parent

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're calling `toString()` after putting stuff into `childObj`.
Anyway, this code should work:

```
JSONObject parent = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject childObj = new JSONObject();

try
{
    //create first child
    childObj
        .put("Name", "foo1")
        .put("Number", 123);

    //insert it into the array
    jArray.put(childObj);
    //... repeat for all remaining elements

    //attach the array to the parent
    parent.put("info",jArray);
}
catch (JSONException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then, to get your JSON as a string for POSTing just call `parent.toString();`

Comment: for my code and which is given u are the same the only diff. is try catch block. Anyway i tried this also but no change

Comment: He also removed `.toString()` from each `childObj.put(...)`. You should call `.toString()` on your parent object in the end instead.